# Codeigniter URI Routing Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I want to show url in title I used this regex is valid or not?

```
$route['go/reference/(:num)/([a-z\_]{0,60}$)'] = "learn/go/reference/$1/$2";
```

can I remove id from url ?

```
www.example.com/go/reference/1/if_else
```

Comment: Is `(:num)` for codeigniter? I think you want `\d+` or `[0-9]+`.

Comment: Use `$route['go/reference/(:num)/(:any)$'] = "learn/go/reference/$1/$2";`. If you do not need the id, just omit it: `$route['go/reference/(:num)/(:any)$'] = "learn/go/reference/$2";`. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thanks for all comment but i use regex not widecard (:any) @stribizhev

Comment: But does the trick with omitting $1/ work?